# Using Git to see file changes locally not on web server

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have done a series of changes on a "demo" backup version of a website before we get approved and move to live. Lots of changes and tweaks have been done, so  difficult to keep a track of.

The web server doesn't have Git installed. So I have downloaded a full FTP backup(version 1) before I did the work and then again after the work has been done(version 2). I then uploaded "version 1" to Bitbucket and then copied the Git folder to version 2 and then commit that too. I'd hoped Therefore to see a nice graphical view of all the files that have changed.

It hasn't worked and  in my 2nd commit, ALL of the files rather than just logging and listing the files that have changed.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of things that could have gone wrong. Did you change file directory paths? introduce white space changes in all the files? You should have realized this was the case when you staged the second set of changes (git diff --staged), it lists your index and you would see all the files listed there as changed. If so and that surprised you, you should have examined the diff to see what changed.

Comment: It just seems to recognise the whole directory as new. Is the above. Would FTP the new copy into the existing git project have been a better solution?